# What's the term of data structure where field is missing if no value?

Tags: data-structures

My data looks like this:

```
[
    {"name":"Jimmy H.","title":"Mr."},  
    {"name": "Janice H."}
]
```

So, if field does not have value, then also the field name is missing. What's the proper term for that?

EDIT:
Basically I'm looking for a term that differentiates structure above from structure where every field name (even without value) is guaranteed to exist in every record.

Answer (score 1):

The one in the example is a combination of well known structures, it seems indeed an `array` of `maps`. At least, in JavaScript it would be an `array` of `objects`, but those `objects` behave like `maps` the way they are used in the example.

Comment: Thanks, I notice now that my question was badly structured. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Well, such a data structure is a map or a dictionary. Otherwise, you are defining an object with a well defined interface. Unfortunately, in JavaScript under the hood an object behaves in a similar way as a map does, so it's hard to discriminate them.

Comment: If talking outside of javascript, then what would be the right term? Schemaless?